# Get the element bound with the object header

Tags: javascript, data-binding, sapui5

I am using a UI5 routing with the parameter and I want to pass a parameter to another view through routing. For the second page's view, I am writing the function to attach the passed parameter to the component.

```
onInit: function () {
    var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
    oRouter.getRoute("personProperties").attachPatternMatched(this._onObjectMatched, this);  
},

_onObjectMatched : function (oEvent) {
    this.getView().byId("oHeader").bindElement({
        path: "/contacts/" + oEvent.getParameter("arguments").personPath,
        model: "person"
    });
}
```

I want to attach the data to the second page's Object Header, which I declared like this.

```
<mvc:View 
    xmlns="sap.m" 
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" 
    xmlns:tnt="sap.tnt" 
    displayBlock="true"
>
    <ObjectHeader title="{person>personId}"></ObjectHeader>
</mvc:View>
```

There is no model attached to the second page. But I want to attach the passed parameter to the header of the title of the object header. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Is person a real model?
Why are you creating the header by JavaScript and not by XML? You could directly bind that model to the view, you just need to use the View bindElement method to do that.

Comment: I have changed to XML view now, and I don't understand what you want to mean 'real model'? Thanks for answer.

Comment: Hi Suhas, "real model" because the code was partial and I cannot get the whole picture like this ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have code like this:

```
 this.getView().byId("oHeader").bindElement({
        path: "/contacts/" + oEvent.getParameter("arguments").personPath,
        model: "person"
    });
```

But, your xml does not show any id "oHeader". I recommend you set the 'bindElement' on the whole view as below (or provide a valid id above):

```
 this.getView().bindElement({
        path: "/contacts/" + oEvent.getParameter("arguments").personPath,
        model: "person"
    });
```

I had to make lot of assumptions here as I can't see all the things I need to see.

Thank you.